# Какой триггер отвечает за наведение мыши на textBox?

Tags: wpf, .net

На форме есть `TextBox`, при наведении на него должно изменяться значение `BorderBrush`. Пробовал через `IsMouseOver`, но не помогло. Пробежался по свойствам на [MDSN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx), но так и не разобрался. Какой триггер/свойство за это отвечает?

Answer (score 3):

```
<TextBox Width="150" Height="50">
  <TextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: не помогает, возможно из-за того, что в проекте есть библиотека от mahApps.

Comment: Это верный ответ. Если не работает, значит что-то перекрывает этот триггер

Comment: @UporotayaPanda, вы в разметке явно не устанавливаете `BorderBrush`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP в разметке нет. Библиотека mahApps может влияет?

Comment: @UporotayaPanda, не должна по идее, иначе это плохая библиотека.